# How to send back the tokens to android using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, python, json, django, firebase-authentication

I am developing an Android app which uses Firebase and my own server running Django. What I intend to do is, I want to first authenticate the user using android app to the django server which then generates the custom tokens as specified in firebase docs. Then I want to send the generated custom token back to the android.

My question is how to send that custom token back to android? I tried to send as JSON object. But it says JWT are not JSON serializable.

I passed the username and password from android app as json object and authenticated with my django server.

Here is my minimal `Django` code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

cred = credentials.Certificate("firebase-admin.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def validateuser(request):
    json_data=json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    try:
        // I verify the username and password and extract the uid
        uid = 'some-uid'
        custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid)

        result={'TAG_SUCCESS': 1, 'CUSTOM_TOKEN': custom_token }
    except:
        result={'TAG_SUCCESS': 0, 'CUSTOM_TOKEN': '0'}


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type='application/json')
```

But it says the custom token is not JSON serializable. Is it not  the way to do like this? How do I send the custom token back to the android app?

And this is the error:

> uid:  78b30d23-6238-4634-b2e4-73cc1f0f7486
>
> custom_token: b'eyJraWQiOiAiZmFlNzA2MzZiY2UwZTk0Y2Y5YTM2OWRlNzc4ZDZlYWQ5NGMwM2MzYiIsICJhbGciOiAiUlMyNTYiLCAidHlwIjogIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiAiZmlyZWJhc2UtYWRtaW5zZGstOXBtbjVAYnVzdHJhY2tlci0xZDE3OS5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsICJ1aWQiOiAiNzhiMzBkMjMtNjIzOC00NjM0LWIyZTQtNzNjYzFmMGY3NDg2IiwgImF1ZCI6ICJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5dG9vbGtpdC5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9nb29nbGUuaWRlbnRpdHkuaWRlbnRpdHl0b29sa2l0LnYxLklkZW50aXR5VG9vbGtpdCIsICJleHAiOiAxNTA4MDc2OTA4LCAiaWF0IjogMTUwODA3MzMwOCwgInN1YiI6ICJmaXJlYmFzZS1hZG1pbnNkay05cG1uNUBidXN0cmFja2VyLTFkMTc5LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIn0=.jgexW_xR5FeZvuO5TPWO8EOBnRJ28ut9OR_OxeajE1_o4ns4fwd2pMXlK2GkM464P5Vi-IxheG-IIJcANxGSDeZgvgpkLfKkHMZeSaraqfEQGq6N7ipuD8o1T7zd5qm79twmFbrQZRB1y7g1-zcjL69x8KFsThWOTmo0TYj5l3zf8_2Cxbw2SGefMWkCwL0d1yQjcUqVyuSAP3-Sg8KrrqCcG4cjNOXKeWxwbUQO7DobOQlT5TfRApwWk8Td6uPjD7d6jqMo-HPKOis0vRoXMBzflZKj36-hIOFkygZNbDWLTsQzbb3HZg8dBabA5GTy--iQi038TRMIm2W0irr0ng=='
>
> Internal Server Error: /api/user/validateuser/ Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 249, in _legacy_get_response
>       response = self._get_response(request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
>   line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/www/Tracker/user/api/views.py", line 251, in
>   validateuser
>       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type='application/json')   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/**init**.py", line 230, in dumps
>       return _default_encoder.encode(obj)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
>       chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
>       return _iterencode(o, 0)   File 
>   "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
>
> ```
> raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are using python3 version. I found what the problem is.

The auth.create_custom_token(uid) method returns a bytes literal and bytes literal are not JSON serializable. That is why you are getting the error. You can see **b'** infront of the jwt token.

So, you need to just convert the byte literal to string using the code below.

```
custom_token = (auth.create_custom_token(uid)).decode()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'